# How to use Check_MK and logwatch to monitor multiple log files as one service?

Tags: jenkins, check-mk

I'm trying to use [Check_MK's logwatch](http://mathias-kettner.com/checkmk_logfiles.html) to send a critical alert (`C`) if a given pattern (e.g., `EOFException`) is found in a large number (~1000) of Jenkins log files. For this, I have created the following simple `logwatch.cfg` file:

```
/var/opt/builddata/jenkins/jobs/*/builds/lastFailedBuild/log
 C EOFException
```

While this basically works, I now get a new service in Check_MK for every log file, completely cluttering the GUI.

Is there any way to configure Check_MK to watch multiple log files as a single service?

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is very old, the answer should be this [logwatch.groups](https://checkmk.com/cms_check_logwatch.groups.html).

Unfortunately this help page is not very helpful. But it is relatively easy to use this. You basically only have to put a text file "fileinfo.cfg" in the same folder and define there which files are a group.

/etc/check_mk/fileinfo.cfg:

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
/var/log/apache2/error.log-*
```

Now, you can use "File Grouping Patterns" in Checkmk to define group names [fileinfo.groups](https://checkmk.de/cms_check_fileinfo.groups.html).
WATO -> Host & Service Parameters -> search for "fileinfo.groups"